# How can I protect my ajax widget?

Tags: ajax, widget, sign

I want to create a widget around an ajax API that I host on my server. The widget would be served by my server, too, and placed on 3rd party web sites. The widget has to have access to the hosting page's DOM (because it accesses form data on the page) so it must be embedded using a script tag rather than in an iframe.

When a button is pressed, the widget will hit my API, receive a response, and insert it into the hosting page's form.

So far so good using script tags and ajax goodness. Had a quick proof of concept running in a few minutes. But how can I keep a 4th party from looking at the code on 3rd party's page and copying it in order to have the widget on their page as well? The widget will be freely available to everyone, but I want to know who's using it and control access. I also want to keep people from accessing the API without the widget.

I've brainstormed a ton of signing and hashing ideas, expiring tokens, a 3rd party server-side proxy, using Flash on the client, and more but I can't come up with something that a determined spoofer can't get around fairly easily.

Put another way, I want to make sure that only the client that rendered the widget can call the API and get a response.

Maybe there's another way to think about this problem?

Comment: Maybe some kind of widget framework? Not seeing anything out there that clearly does this.

Comment: OAuth? OpenID? I'm a little overwhelmed by these concepts. Not sure if any of them are a good fit here...

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone interested, I've come up with a solution:

I'm requiring my widget to be shown only on pages requiring a login to the 3rd party web site. i.e. Not on publicly available pages.

I will also require the 3rd party web site to embed a few lines of server-side code (e.g. PHP) that generate a random nonce and combine it with a secret key and create a hash:

$nonce = make_nonce();
$secret = 'key specific to this provider';
$hash = sha1($nonce . $secret);

The nonce and hash will be sent along with requests to my server so I can validate that they come from a browser that is correctly logged into the 3rd party system. I'll return an API access token to the browser that can be used in hits to the API.

This ties API access to specific 3rd party integrators.

Then to limit abuse, I'll rate-limit the access tokens so that they're good for one interactive user but not for programmatic use.

I'll also record the nonces used and make them single-use, plus rate-limit the ability to get access tokens so someone with a login to the 3rd party site can't keep getting a new access token for every request they want to make.

This should limit the potential for abuse significantly without affecting real customers at all.

Comment: Another thing you could do is whitelist authorized websites so only they can make requests (I'm not too sure if you can get from what page it's being requested consequently though, unless they use a php script to fetch it from you in which case you can use authentication stuff (Which you already sort of did))

Comment: Oops, didn't see this response right away. I'd do that except all requests are coming from the client. I think what I've proposed is going to work well if I tweak the rate limiting a bit.